# How to print multiple text lines in LC3

Tags: lc3

I am trying to write three lines of text in lc3 and I want to print them to the console with .stringz Here's my code so far. With this way I'm only getting the first line to print. Any suggestions?

```
; LC3 program that displays my name and id number to console
; then the user inputs two variables and they will be added 
; and the sum printed to the console
    .ORIG x3000
    LEA R0, NAME
    LEA R1, FIRST
    LEA R2, SECOND
    PUTS
    PUTS
    HALT
NAME    .STRINGZ "Thomas Collier"
FIRST   .STRINGZ "PLease enter first number between 0 and 9:"
SECOND  .STRINGZ "Please enter second number between 0 and 9:"  
    .END
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only printing the string stored in NAME because the PUTs routine only prints out what the pointer stored in R0 points to. You would need to do something like the following:

```
LEA R0, NAME
PUTS
LEA R0, FIRST
PUTS
LEA R0, SECOND
PUTS
HALT
```